# Unexpected value 'DataTablesModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, datatables

I am new to Angular Data tables and I am trying to implement Angular Data tables by following the instructions given in the link https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

after following the instructions when I try to run the application using Angular CLI  I am getting  Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'DataTablesModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Note: I have added DataTablesModule in my app.module.ts as shown below

```
import { ActionComponent } from './action/action.component';
import { SearchfilterPipe } from './search/searchfilter.pipe';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
routingComponents,
LicenseComponent,
HeaderComponent,
ActionComponent,
FooterComponent,
SearchfilterPipe

],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpModule,
FormsModule,
DataTablesModule,
AppRoutingModule,
NgbModule.forRoot()
],
providers: [HttpModule],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and in .angular-cli.json I have added the below code

```
{
"apps": [
{
  ...
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
  ],
  ...
 }
 ]
 }
```

I am using the below provided versions.

@angular/cli: 1.1.0
 node: 8.0.0
  @angular/compiler: 4.2.3
 @angular/core: 4.2.6
 @angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.3

Not understanding why exactly my application is crashing.Any Inputs/Suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can u please show your code ?

Comment: added the code.

Comment: `angular-datatables` includes `node_modules` folder. That's why you're getting this error. I would say it's a bug

Comment: what would be the better  solution then?

Comment: Try removing `node_modules/angular/datatables/node_modules` folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First modify your `tsconfig.json` and add this block inside

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/*"
     ]
    }
  }
}
```

Next, `angular-datatables` actually installs a version of `node_modules` and includes a copy of `@angular` inside of it and this causes a conflict between angular versions so just remove the `node_modules` from `angular-datatables` folder and you're good to go.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  This worked for me, but that's an obnoxious solution.  I can't imagine how poorly this is going to to for me when I try and do this on my docker container

Answer (score 0):

You can run in aot

```
ng serve --aot
```

or use the --preserve-links option

```
ng serve --preserve-symlinks
```